# Exploring/Iterating UI Event's

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, events, uicontrol

In a C# Application we can add an **Event Handler** like `this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click);` also we can Remove `this.button3.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click);` so it means we can add as much as we want event's in an UI Control ,so my question is how can i Explore or Iterate and Remove a Specific Event from an UI .
Eg . If we can in someway populate all Events of an Control on a **ListBox** (if it's possible) and remove the Selected One .

PS : Im kinda a Junior Programmer ,so i think Code Reflection handles this portion.
Bests

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989889/store-a-list-of-eventhandlers-to-unsubscribe-from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily display a list of all possible events for your component with a code like

```
EventInfo[] allEvents = Button1.GetType().GetEvents(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
    | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
foreach (EventInfo curEvent in allEvents)
{
    EventsListBox.Items.Add(curEvent.Name);
}
```

However, it seems impossible to know which methods are assigned to the delegates, that will be called in case of an event, outside of the component. You can refer to [How do I find out if a particular delegate has already been assigned to an event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093442/how-do-i-find-out-if-a-particular-delegate-has-already-been-assigned-to-an-event), [Determine list of event handlers bound to event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660480/determine-list-of-event-handlers-bound-to-event) and [Iterating through event handlers](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/536b810f-c5f0-44e9-be24-f7b55d424549/)