# How can I create a dynamic method to handle an event?

Tags: c#, dynamicmethod

In C#, how can I create a dynamic method that can be used to handle an event?

Here is an event:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> refresh;
```

Here is a method:

```
public void Test()
{

}
```

How can I dynamically create a method to handle the refresh event, such that the dynamic method calls the Test method?

The Test method above is an example of a method to be called.

Comment: Why can't you just subscribe to that event and call the Test method from there?

Comment: The code is for users to subscribe to events at runtime. The above method to call is just an example.

Comment: So "refresh" is an event from a class and Test is a method that is not part of that class?

Comment: Yes. "Test" can be in any class. The object that has the "Test" method is already instantiated.

Comment: Anyway, you could take a look at this answer to a similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/45901/6347013

Comment: Can you please provide more examples of the methods that your would like dynamically called?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could simply subscribe to the event.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> refresh;
}

public void Test()
{
}

void Main()
{
    var some = new SomeClass();
    some.refresh += (sender, e) => Test();
    // or
    some.refresh += Refreshed;
}

void Refreshed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Test();
}
```

Comment: This is what I am wanting to do, but I am in need of help on how to create the "Refreshed" method dynamically.

Comment: Can't you tell us why it need to be created dynamically?

Comment: The "Test' method is an example of a method than can be called. A user can choose any method to be called. As such, it has to be created dynamically.

Comment: I guess that's the kind of information I would write in a question.

Comment: @user3736648 if "A user can choose any method to be called" ie. a drop down list, you could drop all subscribed events ([See here for some pre-baked code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-a-control)), then subscribe to the selected method `some.refresh += (sender, e) => ChoosenMethod();`. Is this what you mean by dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

If the method you want to invoke is an instance method in some class and you have an instance of that class and the name of the method, you can use [`Delegate.CreateDelegate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12f294ye) to create a delegate to that method and then use a lambda to invoke it in an event handler:

```
static EventHandler<EventArgs> CreateHandler(object methodObject, string methodName)
{
    var methodDelegate =
        (Action)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), methodObject, methodName);

    return (s, e) => methodDelegate();
}
```

Usage can then look like this (assuming `Test` is in class `C`):

```
refresh += CreateHandler(new C(), "Test");

refresh(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Comment: @downvoter What do you think is wrong with this answer?